# Date time conversion in Java8

Tags: java, datetime-format, isodate

I tried searching across the web, but unable to find a suitable answer and hence posting here.
I am calling another API which gives me the date-time like
"2022-02-05T17:13:20-06:00[America/Chicago]"
I would like to convert this to a format like
"2022-02-05T17:13:20.000Z" (I am unsure what the milli-second will turn out as)
Could someone help me achieve this?
I am unable to get any example for this specific conversion scenario!!!

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: There is no way that `2022-01-05` can ever be `2022-06-21`

Comment: I just meant the format... not the value exactly... ok.. Let me update the question to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

For the sample values given getting to a UTC timestamp should be something like

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("2022-02-05T17:13:20-06:00[America/Chicago]").toInstant().toString()
```

The datetime value including the timezone is the canonical representation of a ZonedDateTime and therefore can be parsed as such.

Instant is a UTC timestamp that prints in the form of 2022-02-05T23:13:20Z

You could take more influence on the behavior using a DateTimeFormatter - but since both input and output seem to be standard formats it does not seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here below is a code snippet that I was able to generate....
But, I am unsure of that is correct. Please let me know if you feel anything is incorrect.

```
String requestTime = "2022-02-05T17:13:20-06:00[America/Chicago]";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX'['VV']'");
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(requestTime, formatter);
        zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"));
        System.out.println(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")));
```

Comment: No, it’s not correct. The trailing `Z` in your result means UTC, so you need to convert from the UTC offset in the string (`-06:00`) to UTC. Drop the first formatter and just parse the string through `ZonedDateTime.parse(requestTime)` since it is in the default format for a `ZonedDateTime`. To convert and format use `String output = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));`. Output will be `2022-02-05T23:13:20.000Z`, which is the correct UTC equivalent to your input.